# Improvements for an evolutionary algorithm with ANNs solving XOR

Tags: java, algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm, mutation, biological-neural-network

I'm supposed to implement an artificial neural network (ANN) with 2 input, 2 hidden and 1 output neuron that can solve the XOR problem. The weights of the network should be optimized using an evolutionary algorithm. The activation function for each neuron and the fitness function for each ANN are given.
The following picture sums up the problem and introduces the variable names I used:

[image]

Now I tried my very best to solve the problem, but even with an evolutionary algorithm using a population size of 1000 ANNs and 2000 generations my best fitness is never better than 0.75. My code includes a ANN class with the neurons, activation and fitness function and a Main class that includes the evolutionary algorithm and that optimizes the weights for the ANNs. Here is the code:

Each ANN is initialized with random weights between -1 and 1 and able to mutate, i.e. return a mutation that differs in one weight wich is chosen randomly.

```
public class ANN implements Comparable<ANN> {
    private Random rand = new Random();
    public double[] w = new double[6];  //weights: in1->h1, in1->h2, in2->h1, in2->h2, h1->out, h2->out

    public ANN() {
        for (int i=0; i<6; i++) //randomly initialize weights in [-1,1)
            w[i] = rand.nextDouble() * 2 - 1;
    }

    //calculates the output for input a & b
    public double ann(double a, double b) {
        double h1 = activationFunc(a*w[0] + b*w[2]);
        double h2 = activationFunc(a*w[1] + b*w[3]);
        double out = activationFunc(h1*w[4] + h2*w[5]);

        return out;
    }

    private double activationFunc(double x) {
        return 2.0 / (1 + Math.exp(-2*x)) - 1;
    }

    //calculates the fitness (divergence to the right output)
    public double fitness() {
        double sum = 0;
        //test all possible inputs (0,0; 0,1; 1,0; 1,1)
        sum += 1 - Math.abs(0 - ann(0, 0));
        sum += 1 - Math.abs(1 - ann(0, 1));
        sum += 1 - Math.abs(1 - ann(1, 0));
        sum += 1 - Math.abs(0 - ann(1, 1));
        return sum / 4.0;
    }

    //randomly change random weight and return the mutated ANN
    public ANN mutate() {
        //copy weights
        ANN mutation = new ANN();
        for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
            mutation.w[i] = w[i];

        //randomly change one
        int weight = rand.nextInt(6);
        mutation.w[weight] = rand.nextDouble() * 2 - 1;

        return mutation;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ANN arg) {
        if (this.fitness() < arg.fitness())
            return -1;
        if (this.fitness() == arg.fitness())
            return 0;
        return 1;   //this.fitness > arg.fitness
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        ANN ann = (ANN)obj;
        for (int i=0; i<w.length; i++) {    //not equal if any weight is different
            if (w[i] != ann.w[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The Main class has the evolutionary algorithm and uses elitism and rank-based selection to create the next generation of each population, i.e. the 100 best ANNs are copied the remaining 900 are mutations of previously successful ANNs.

```
//rank-based selection + elitism
public class Main {
    static Random rand = new Random();
    static int size = 1000;                     //population size
    static int elitists = 100;                  //number of elitists

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int generation = 0;
        ArrayList<ANN> population = initPopulation();
        print(population, generation);

        //stop after good fitness is reached or after 2000 generations
        while(bestFitness(population) < 0.8 && generation < 2000) {
            generation++;
            population = nextGeneration(population);
            print(population, generation);
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<ANN> initPopulation() {
        ArrayList<ANN> population = new ArrayList<ANN>();
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            ANN ann = new ANN();
            if (!population.contains(ann))  //no duplicates
                population.add(ann);
        }
        return population;
    }

    public static ArrayList<ANN> nextGeneration(ArrayList<ANN> current) {
        ArrayList<ANN> next = new ArrayList<ANN>();
        Collections.sort(current, Collections.reverseOrder());  //sort according to fitness (0=best, 999=worst)

        //copy elitists
        for (int i=0; i<elitists; i++) {
            next.add(current.get(i));
        }

        //rank-based roulette wheel
        while (next.size() < size) {                        //keep same population size
            double total = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
                total += 1.0 / (i + 1.0);                   //fitness = 1/(rank+1)

            double r = rand.nextDouble() * total;
            double cap = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
                cap += 1.0 / (i + 1.0);                     //higher rank => higher probability
                if (r < cap) {                              //select for mutation
                    ANN mutation = current.get(i).mutate(); //no duplicates
                    if (!next.contains(mutation))
                        next.add(mutation);     
                    break;
                }
            }
        }       

        return next;
    }

    //returns best ANN in the specified population
    public static ANN best(ArrayList<ANN> population) {
        Collections.sort(population, Collections.reverseOrder());
        return population.get(0);
    }

    //returns the best fitness of the specified population
    public static double bestFitness(ArrayList<ANN> population) {
        return best(population).fitness();
    }

    //returns the average fitness of the specified population
    public static double averageFitness(ArrayList<ANN> population) {
        double totalFitness = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            totalFitness += population.get(i).fitness();
        double average = totalFitness / size;
        return average;
    }

    //print population best and average fitness
    public static void print(ArrayList<ANN> population, int generation) {       
        System.out.println("Generation: " + generation + "\nBest: " + bestFitness(population) + ", average: " + averageFitness(population));
        System.out.print("Best weights: ");
        ANN best = best(population);
        for (int i=0; i<best.w.length; i++)
            System.out.print(best.w[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Even though, I put quite some thought into this and used techniques that I learned, the result is not satisfying. For some reason the optimal weights seem to drift to -1 for each weight. How does that make sense? Is the range of -1 to 1 for the weights a good choice? Should I also introduce crossovers in addition to the mutations?
I know this is a very specific problem, but I would greatly appreciate some help!

Comment: That's some pretty strong elitism. Have you tried using less elitist selection? It's possible that having all weights be -1 is an easy to reach but suboptimal fitness peak, which is exactly the sort of problem that elitism has trouble with. Also, have you tried using a bias node?

Comment: What do you mean with strong elitism? Too many elitists? No I haven't tried a bias node. How does that work for ANNs with hidden layers? Is the bias node just an additional input neuron or is it also represented in the hidden layer?

Comment: Sorry, by "strong elitism" I mean that 10% of your population is a lot to be guaranteed to survive. Instead, I would suggest using some sort of tournament selection: to create each new member of the population, select a random group of population members, choose the best of the group, and randomly decide whether or not to mutate it. This way, all members of the population have a chance of making it to the next generation, but fitter ones are more likely to. The size of the group is an important parameter - for a population of 1000, 50 is probably reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

The network structure is not right. Without a bias or threshold for each node this network cannot solve the XOR problem.

One hidden node should encode the OR and the other hidden node should encode for the AND. Then the output node can encode that the OR hidden node is positive and the AND hidden node is negative for the XOR problem. This only results in positive outcomes when the OR hidden node is activated and the AND hidden node is not.

I would also increase the boundaries on the weights, let the EA find it out by itself. But it depends on the network structure if that is necessary.

If you want to use this network with hidden nodes and thresholds see: http://www.heatonresearch.com/online/introduction-neural-networks-java-edition-2/chapter-1/page4.html

If you want to use another network with biases see: http://www.mind.ilstu.edu/curriculum/artificial_neural_net/xor_problem_and_solution.php